# Non-crystallographic cluster algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cluster-algebras, recurrences, almost-periodic-function, root-systems

### Background

Fomin and Zelevinsky have introduced cluster algebras in an [influential article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104151). To define a cluster algebra, Fomin and Zelevinsky have defined a *mutation of seeds*. Here, a *seed* $(\mathbf{x},B)$ consists of a *cluster* $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of certain elements (which are called *cluster variables*) and a skew-symmetrisable integer $n\times n$ matrix $B$. By definition, the cluster algebra is generated by all cluster variables in all seeds that are obtained from a given initial seed by a sequence of mutations.

A skew-symmetrisable integer $2\times 2$ matrix has the form $$B=\pm\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\\\-b&0\end{pmatrix}$$ for some natural numbers $a,b\geq 1$. Note that the two possible choices yield isomorphic cluster algebras that we denote by $\mathcal{A}(a,b)$. We can parametrise the cluster variables in $\mathcal{A}(a,b)$ by the set of integers, so that we obtain cluster variables $x_i$, with $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, and clusters $(x_{i-1},x_i)$, with $i\in\mathbb{Z}$. The equation
\begin{align*}
x_{i-1}x_{i+1}=\begin{cases}x_i^a+1,& \textrm{if } i \textrm{ is even}, \\\\ x_i^b+1,&\textrm{if } i \textrm{ is odd,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
describes the mutation from the cluster $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ to the cluster $(x_i,x_{i+1})$.

There are two kinds of cluster algebras: cluster algebras of *finite type* and cluster algebras of *infinite type*. We declare a cluster algebra to be of finite type if it admits only finitely many cluster variables. [Fomin and Zelevinsky](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208229) have furthermore classified cluster algebras of finite type by finite type root systems. We therefore see that (coefficient-free) cluster algebras (without frozen variables) are in bijection with *Dynkin diagrams* of type $A_n (n \geq 1)$, $B_n (n\geq 2)$, $C_n (n\geq 3)$, $D_n (n\geq 4)$, $E_n (n=6,7,8)$, $F_4$, and $G_2$. The classification theorem implies that the cluster algebra $\mathcal{A}(a,b)$ from above is of finite type if and only if $ab<4$. In this case, the sequence is $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is periodic.

Dynkin diagrams satisfy a crystallographic condition. In the context of cluster algebras, the crystallographic condition yields integer entries in the $B$-matrix. On the other hand, finite Coxeter groups are in bijection with *Coxeter-Dynkin* diagrams. Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams do not necessarily satisfy a crystallographic condition. Examples of non-crystallographic Coxeter groups are dihedral groups (with Coxeter-Dynkin diagram $I_2(m)$ with $m=5$ or $m\geq 7$) and the symmetry group of the icosahedron (with Coxeter-Dynkin diagram $H_3$).

---

### Recurrences associated with non-crystallographic root systems

The Dynkin diagrams associated with the cluster algebras $\mathcal{A}(1,1)$, $\mathcal{A}(2,1)$ and $\mathcal{A}(3,1)$ are $A_2$, $B_2$ and $G_2$, respectively. Viewed as Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams, the corresponding Coxeter groups are the dihedral symmetry groups of the equilateral triangle, the square and the regular hexagon. More generally, the Coxeter-Dynkin diagram associated with the dihedral group of symmetries of the regular $m$-gon, for some $m\geq 3$, consists of two vertices that are joined by an edge of weight $a=4\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{m})$. Putting $b=1$, we can define a sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ as above.

In the case $m=5$ (where we have $a=4\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{5})=\frac12(3+\sqrt{5})\approx2.618033988$) my computer algebra system has randomly choosen various starting values $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the interval $(0,1)$ and computed the first few terms numerically. It turns out that after 14 steps, we always get close to our starting values, as the following example illustrates:

0.9449133500
0.2109364289
1.076295668
9.843229446
370.8734823
37.77962145
36.31787856
0.9877779910
0.05419694189
1.067240769
40.32970628
38.72575663
356.3222202
9.226991316
0.9462529267
0.2109303955

The same phenomenon also holds for other values of $m$, and the number of steps seems to be either $m+2$ or $2(m+2)$.

**Questions:**

1. What's going on? I have computed the first terms in the sequence for $m=5$ in exact form, and it seems unlikely to me that the sequence is periodic on the nose. (Although I might have to try harder and deviations in the experiments come from computation errors.)

   [Fomin and Reading](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505518) and other authors have generalised the Lie theoretic combinatorics of cluster algebras to general root systems. Have some authors also generalised cluster algebras to general root systems? For example, does a sophisticated version of the *Laurent phenomenon* hold in this case?

Comment: This has been asked a long time ago (2005), see page 13 of http://www.aimath.org/WWN/braidgroups/braidgroups.pdf

Comment: There is a "non-crystallographic folding" (A_4 to the dihedral group of order 10, D_6 to H_3, E_8 to H_4, and other A's to other odd dihedral groups, and D's to even dihedral groups).  I have hoped that something like this should be involved, but I don't see how it would be.